# Can't set "LANG" environment variable through /etc/default/locale

Tags: debian, kde, locale, language

I'm running the following setup

- Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.14.5

(I'm also using Awesome WM if that's relevant)

Following the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale), I've run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to generate locales and set my `/etc/default/locale` to the following:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:fr"
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

That is, I'm trying to get every information in english, except for dates, measurements, etc.

When I type `locale`, I get this:

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:fr
LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

When I type `locale -a`, I get:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
```

As you can see, `LANG` is set to `fr_FR.UTF-8`, while I'd like it to be `en_US.UTF-8`. Is there something wrong with my `/etc/default/locale` syntax ? What could possibly override its content and be considered at login time instead ? KDE regional settings seem to be only american english (and KDE menus/windows are indeed in english).

Comment: You need to add what «locale -a» outputs

Comment: @Rusi just edited my post to add this output.

Comment: Welcome , could you add the output of `grep 'LANG\|LC' ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Check your [pam_environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4-.2F.pam_environment)?

Comment: Hi @GAD3R, nothing except this little commented hacky line:
`# LANG="en_US.UTF-8"; export LANG`
(See my answer to Yasien Dwieb below)

Comment: No `~/.pam_environment` file in my home dir @Rusi !

Comment: The `en_US:fr` doesn't exist, is it a typo? you can check the supported locales through `cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`

Comment: @GAD3R, this was a priority list of the [LANGUAGE](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html) variable. Actually it didn't make much sense for me to use this variable and to put english before any other language in this list (since this is the 'ultimate' fallback language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after @GAD3R's comment, I realized my `LANGUAGE` variable setting wasn't really consistent with what I wanted : english messages by default, french units / dates, etc. 
I set it back to only `en_US`, and something weird happened : when logging into awesome WM, the output of `locale` was what I'd expected and everything worked fine, but not when logging into KDE Plasma.

With Plasma, I still had `LANGUAGE=en_US:fr` printed in the `locale` output ! I finally checked the plasma regional settings, and spotted that there was no default language set. I set it to 'American English', checked the 'Detailed settings' checkbox in the 'Formats' menu (everything was already filled in accordance to the configuration file), logged out and back in and the problem was solved.

I guess that filling stuff inside Plasma settings was necessary, even if everything had been configured through the `/etc/` config file already.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this in your .bashrc file as follows

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

And put remaining values as so

Comment: Thanks. I know I can set the environment variable through a bashrc file, but this sounds hacky and I'd rather know why some of the variables from my `/etc` file are considered while `LANG` is overriden.